# CSS: Responsive vertical columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have a basic vertical column layout. [See jsbin for example](http://jsbin.com/zovoguqe/1). I'm now wanting to make it responsive so that the smaller the screen the far left handed columns fall off (not displayed) one by one. The only catch is that the `<article role="main">` may or may not be on the page. So the css has to work for all the examples below. I appreciate all thoughts/suggestions :)

**Example 1:**

```
<nav role="navigation"></nav>
<main role="site">
  <article role="list"></article>
  <article role="list"></article>
  <article role="main"></article>
</main>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<nav role="navigation"></nav>
<main role="site">
  <article role="list"></article>
  <article role="list"></article>
  ...
</main>
```

**Example 3:**

```
<nav role="navigation"></nav>
<main role="site">
  <article role="list"></article>
</main>
```

==========

## Update:

I updated the [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zovoguqe/1) so that the overflow-y is hidden and that the `<article role="main">` has a min-width.

**Unsolved:** Can someone show me how to order the columns so that as the screen gets smaller the last column is always displayed, the first column is hidden first, the second column is hidden next, etc..? (I'd prefer not to use media queries if at all possible.)

## Update 2:

I added media queries to the [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zovoguqe/4) and it's now working how I wanted. If you know how to accomplish this solution without them, feel free to post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your three side-menus should really just be one menu with some jquery panels and you'd make your responsive interface much easier to manage. Breaking a menu into three divs like this would be madness for screenreaders and people with disabilities.

Comment: @staypuftman - I'm using angular to load each of the columns into the dom much like jquery panels. The `<nav>` is separate so it can be a sliding side menu. Though I am a bit confused still, hence this post ;)

Comment: Just curious, but why delete major content from the page as the screen gets smaller? Why not stack the columns instead so mobile users aren't getting a stripped-down menu?

Comment: @Timmah - this layout structure is for an angular app so each column represents it's own page. On smaller screens users can slide back to the previous column (page) or swipe for the navigation. On larger screens users can see all columns (pages) at once.

Answer (score 2):

I really wish i could post it as comment, but it is too long for that

Dont' know weather it works, couldn't try and test. So giving it like a plain thought.
If you can add class to them, it might be easy.
1. Add class navigation to , and articles to 
so,

```
@media all and (max-width: 360px){
 .navigation{ display: none; }
 .article {display: none;}
 /* and CSS to the MAIN content */ }

@media all and (max-width: 480px){
 .navigation{ display: none; }
 .article:first-child {display: none;}
 /* and CSS to the MAIN content and last child of sub nav */
```

}

```
@media all and (max-width: 780px){
 .navigation{ /* CSs comes here */ }
 .article { /* CSs comes here */ }
 /* and CSS to the MAIN content */ }
```